# Customize exception messages from try-catch

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I'm currently into something that I know it is possible, but not sure how to do it.

I want to display an customized error message in a program that people can insert data, delete, update, search and other things like that.
Sadly, I can't just show the message like it here:

```
try { }
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

All I need is a number that describes the exception. So, if I know the specific number, I can associate with the message I want. I tried the following code, but I don't know how to associate the exception I get (is there any library or something?).

I'm doing that because the users won't speak English at all.

I have seen some cases in which people who knows the exception (like divide by zero) can customize it. But, As I will have different messages, I should do it another way.

```
try
{
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.HResult.ToString()); //Here I cant get a number, and, 
   }      //in one case, I get the result 2147467259 which should be about 
}         //inserting a data too long in a MySQL table
```

Comment: Create a custom class, which inherits from Exception, and takes a number as a parameter in its' constructor.

Comment: so you have tested this out and when you test it, you get multiple exceptions? so you can't narrow down which exception is likely to happen?

Comment: So, are you trying to output a numerical code specific to each type of exception? For example "Error: Exception 12345" tells you that you have an index out of bounds exception but "Error: Exception 67890" at the same place tells you that you have a database connection error? Or do you want to output an error code that's specific to each try/catch? For example, "Error: Exception 1" tells you that an exception was caught in try/catch block 1?

Comment: Look up "C# String internationalization" on Google. It shows how you can give each string a name, and use the appropriate language according to the user's settings.

Comment: Bville - Yes.
Tophandour - The first example. ""Error: Exception 12345" tells you that you have an index out of bounds";

Comment: I'm sorry Andrew. Didn't get what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bro, I will Suggest you to first analyze the cause of the exception and then write a custom message, Another Rough thing you can do is check the message of exception and perform something like this in with **Exception** object

```
if(ex.Message.Contains("PRIMARY_KEY"))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Primary Key Violation, You Cannot Add Duplicate Records!");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not have this option "contains".

Comment: I Edited My Answer,, Now you can have the **Contains()** Method

Comment: I see. I can't compile right now, but do u know if it's possible to do something like: if(ex.Message.Contains.("Data too long")). Then blablabla

Comment: Yes I am sure bro, Make sure you type the Message Correctly(No Spelling Mistakes or Extra Spaces)

Comment: You are Welcome bro! :)